# Fix NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, string, nullpointerexception

I'm writing code to read a text file and count all the words in the text file. But in the while loop the string array is getting a NullPointerException. I kinda understand that it means the object is not being pointed to or something along those lines but i cant figure out how to fix it.

```
public class W273 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        while (JPL.test()) {
            String fileName = "phillip.txt";
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line = in.readLine();
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            int count = 0;
            String loop;
            while (in != null) {
                // move this line
                words = line.split(" ");

                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                    loop = words[i]; // NullPointerException here
                    count++;
                }

                line = in.readLine();
            }
            in.close();
            System.out.print(count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I bet that is not where your NPE happens.

Comment: I see an infinite loop here...

Comment: Did you mean `while (line != null)`? Also, you might want to look into the `do { } while (test);` structure. You could eliminate the redundant initial capture of the `line`.

Comment: Post the **full** stack trace, please. **Edit it into the question**.

Comment: @owlstead: that question was meant for OP, `in` can't be null anywhere in that while loop.

Comment: As @Cory pointed out, you're testing the wrong variable. When end-of-file is reached, `line` will be `null` and the NPE will occur on `line.split`.

Comment: Thanks guys. Cory you were right I miss spelled. Fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program could use some restructuring. Here's how I might approach it:

Minimize your field declarations. You don't need the initial definitions of `line` or `words`

```
String fileName = "phillip.txt";
String line;
int count = 0;
BufferedReader in;
```

Be careful with streams. You should handle when there are exceptions to reading files:

```
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
```

Next, assign `line` and check if the result of the assignment operator is `null`. When there are no more lines in the file, the test will fail and the loop will exit.

```
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
```

You can increment `count` all in one line. You don't seem to be doing anything with `loop` or `words`, so for now I've omitted that from this example.

```
        count += line.split(" ").length;
    }
```

Close the buffered reader (no matter what!) and exit.

```
} finally {
    if (in != null)
        in.close();
}
System.out.print(count);
```

Comment: That is awesome thank you, so much more efficient. Just a question: if the count is 76403 but i know it should actually be 73057 what do you think could be the issue with the code?

Comment: Maybe your file has a lot of double-spaces in it? Try `line.split(" +");` instead to ignore more than one consecutive space.

Comment: Down to 73946. Would it be counting numbers as well? Sorry I'm a student so little variations on things like line.split(" +") is new to me. You can learn methods and such but the little things you need to be shown. So thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah there might be all sorts of things in the text, like ellipses, non-breaking spaces, carriage returns, line feeds, and a whole slew of other weird characters. Maybe somewhere there is " ." or " !" (an accidental space causing the period or exclamation point to be counted as their own words). Without seeing the text it would be hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

> I kinda understand that it means the object is not being pointed to or something along those lines but i cant figure out how to fix it.

It doesn't mean that at all.  It means you used a DOT operator on a reference that points to null rather than to an object (i.e. there is no object here at all).

```
words = line.split(" ");
```

line is null, so calling line.split causes the null pointer exception.

```
if(line!=null)
{
    words = line.split(" ");
}
```

The ultimate cause is your while loop.

```
while (in != null) {
```

should be

```
 while ((line=in.readLine()) != null) {
```

That is, loop until the first time you read a line that's null.

Comment: _object that is null_ means the same as _object is not being pointed to_ so you're not really correcting them there. I would say: you're invoking a method (or accessing a field) on a null reference.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, No, its not that the object is not being pointed to but that the object is pointing to null. His explanation is like the object is there but not being pointed to. The object isn't there somewhere in limbo unpointed to. The object is pointing to nothing.

Comment: No, that's even worse. An object is not something that points to anything. An object cannot be null. A reference can be null. A variable can store a null reference. But an object being null is nonsense.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, Is what I have now ok?

Comment: Yes, I think that's much clearer and technically correct.